# how to active class is equal to true for multiple ng-repeats for up and down arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs

.I completed auto complete search for single ng-repeat but my problem with listed items with multiple  ng-repeat.

my html code is:

```
    <section class="input-group"  ng-controller="sidemenu">
<div class="input-group-btn srch-city-list">
    <select  ng-model="SelectCity" class="form-control"
             ng-options="c as c.city_name for c in  Citys" ng-change="changeCity()">
        <img src="images/arrow.png" alt="Arrow"/>
        <option value="">All Cities</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="input-group" arrow-selector>
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter location, builder or project"  ng-model="NodeId_1" autofocus  ng-keyup="getValue($event.keyCode)" />
    <div class="search-datalist" ng-if="showsearch">
        <ul ng-if="resultOfBuldDet.length>0">
            <span class="result-hd">Builders55</span>
            <li  ng-repeat="bud in resultOfBuldDet"  ng-class="{active :$index == focusIndex}" ng-click="searchFilter(bud)"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> {{bud.builders_name}}</li>
        </ul>
        <ul ng-if="resultOfPropDet.length>0">
            <span class="result-hd">Properties22</span>
            <li ng-repeat="prop in resultOfPropDet"  ng-class="{active :$index == focusIndex}" ng-click="searchFilter(prop)"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> {{prop.property_name}} ,{{prop.hp_city.city_name}},{{prop.hp_location.location_name}} </li>
        </ul>
</div>
</section>
```

In this i have a multiple ng-repeats like resultOfBuldDet,resultOfPropDet,etc.

I follwed this link 
https://code.ciphertrick.com/2015/03/15/change-row-selection-using-arrows-in-ng-repeat/

1. Its working for fine but its for single ng-repeat.so how can handle
   this line ng-class="{active :$index == focusIndex}" for  multiple ng-repeats

my dirctive code:

```
sidemenu.directive('arrowSelector',['$document',function($document){
    return{
        restrict:'A',
        link:function(scope,elem,attrs,ctrl){
            var elemFocus = false;
            elem.on('mouseenter',function(){
                elemFocus = true;
            });
            elem.on('mouseleave',function(){
                elemFocus = false;
            });
            $document.bind('keydown',function(e){
                if(elemFocus){
                    if(e.keyCode == 38){
                        console.log(scope.allLength);
                        console.log(scope.focusIndex);
                        if(scope.focusIndex == 0){
                            return;
                        }
                        scope.focusIndex--;
                        scope.$apply();
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                    if(e.keyCode == 40){
                        console.log(scope.allLength);
                        console.log(scope.focusIndex);
                        if(scope.focusIndex == scope.allLength){
                            scope.focusIndex=0;
                            return;
                        }
                        scope.focusIndex++;
                        console.log(scope.focusIndex);
                        scope.$apply();
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

controller code :

```
    sidemenu.controller('sidemenu', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'menuBuildersServices', 'allCityServices',
                'allCountryServices', 'allServices', '$location', '$uibModal',
                '$routeParams', '$mdDialog', 'PropertyDetails', 'customVariables', '$mdSidenav',
                function(a, b, m, c, d, e, l, u, r, v, h, cust, md) {

   a.focusIndex=0;
      if (key == 8 && a.NodeId_1.length <= 2) {
                    a.resultOfPropDet = "";
                    a.resultOfBuldDet = "";
                    a.resultOfLocaDet = "";
                    a.resultOfCityDet = "";
                    a.resultOfSubLocaDet = "";
                }

                if (a.NodeId_1.length > 2 && key!=13) {
                    e.searchList(a.NodeId_1).then(function(result) {
                        a.resultOfPropDet = result.data.resultOfPropDet;
                        a.resultOfBuldDet = result.data.resultOfBuldDet;
                        a.resultOfLocaDet = result.data.resultOfLocaDet;
                        a.resultOfCityDet = result.data.resultOfCityDet;
                        a.resultOfSubLocaDet = result.data.resultOfSubLocaDet;
                        a.showsearch = true;

                        a.allLength=    (a.resultOfPropDet.length+a.resultOfBuldDet.length);

                      }, function(error) {

                    });
                }
    });
```

its working only for single ng-repeat .so how can i handle $index value according to multiple ng-repeats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this line

```
<li ng-repeat="prop in resultOfPropDet"  ng-class="{active :$index == focusIndex} ...
```

with

```
<li ng-repeat="prop in resultOfPropDet"  ng-class="{active :$index == (focusIndex-resultOfBuldDet.length) } ...
```

so focus index continue to the second list when it get bigger than the first list size.

**to extend answer for another list**

add lists in template

```
<li ng-repeat="prop in resultOfLocaDet"  ng-class="{active :$index == (focusIndex-resultOfBuldDet.length - resultOfPropDet.length) } ...
<li ng-repeat="prop in resultOfCityDet"  ng-class="{active :$index == (focusIndex-resultOfBuldDet.length - resultOfPropDet.length - resultOfLocaDet.length) } ...
```

and change allLength to have sum of them

```
a.allLength= a.resultOfPropDet.length + a.resultOfBuldDet.length + a.resultOfLocaDet.length + a.resultOfCityDet.length;
```

Comment: ng-class="{active :$index == (focusIndex-resultOfPropDet.length-resultOfBuldDet.length-resultOfLocaDet.length-resultOfSubLocaDet.length)}"

Comment: i tried this but its not working resultOfcityDet.‌​length

Comment: yes i added a.allLength=(a.resultOfPropDet.length+a.resultOfBuldDet.length+a.resultOfLocaDet.length+a.resultOfCityDet.length+a.resultOfSubLocaDet.length);

Comment: ng-class="{active :$index == focusIndex} problem in this line.if builders not found .i setted this line  $index for only resultOfBuldDet